# iOS: How to subscribe a customer to an Automatically Renewable Subscription

Tags: ios, storekit

What are the most basic steps you need to subscribe to an Automatically Renewable Subscription for iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. Assuming you know the `productID`:

First

```
import StoreKit
```

Then in your code

```
let productID: Set = ["monthly"]
let request = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productID)
request.delegate = self
request.start()
```

and in the `SKProductsRequestDelegate`:

```
if response.products.count > 0 {
  let product = response.products[0]
  let payment = SKPayment(product: product)
  SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addPayment(payment)
}
```

Your're all welcome